# Image quality is reducing after capturing it

Tags: java, android, image, mobile, native

I am capturing photo from camera and save it to gallery but its quality is reducing.
i am not using an library for image loading and capturing and fro cropping i am using Android Image Cropper. Here is code:

```
    @SuppressLint({"QueryPermissionsNeeded", "NonConstantResourceId"})
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.scanBtn:
            showDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.layoutcam:
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(requireActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)   

    {
                takePictureLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.layoutlib:
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,   
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            pickImageLauncher.launch(intent);
            break;
    }
    }

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> takePictureLauncher =    
    registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                String fileName = "my_image.png";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
                Uri selectedImageUri = 
    requireActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,        
    values);
                OutputStream outputStream;
                try {
                    outputStream = 
    requireActivity().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(selectedImageUri);
                    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream); // Change   
    to PNG and reduce quality to 100
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                CropImage.activity(selectedImageUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setRequestedSize(1080, 1080,   
    CropImageView.RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE) // Increase resolution
                        .setOutputCompressQuality(90) // Reduce compression quality
                        .setMaxCropResultSize(1080, 1080)
                        .start(requireContext(), ScanFragment.this);
            }
        });

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new 
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent data = result.getData();
                // Get the selected image URI
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                CropImage.activity(selectedImageUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setRequestedSize(1080, 1080,  
    CropImageView.RequestSizeOptions.RESIZE_INSIDE) // Increase resolution
                        .setOutputCompressQuality(90) // Reduce compression quality
                        .setMaxCropResultSize(1080, 1080)
                        .start(requireContext(), ScanFragment.this);
            }
        });

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri croppedImageUri = result.getUri();
            imageView.setImageURI(croppedImageUri);
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            recognizeText(bitmap);
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
            // Handle cropping error
        }
    }
    }
```

Its in the takePictureLauncher method if anybody can point out and help me fix the bugs its will huge favour.

I tired different compression format and change the quality but nothing worked.

Comment: You are getting a bitmap of a thumbnail. You dont get the original picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` extra field only contains a thumbnail, [as described in the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ImageCapture):

> **Note:** When you use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to capture a photo, the camera might also return a downscaled copy, or thumbnail, of the photo in the result `Intent`, saved as a `Bitmap` in an extra field named `"data"`.

You need to add the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra with a URI pointing at the file location you want to save to, like it describes. Then when you get a successful result, you can load you image from that URI. Full-size images are too big to be passed around in `Intent`s and `Bundle`s.

Comment: Thanks alot, one more error solved thanks.